# How do call custom function on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am aware of `Jquery` events click,focus,focusout . How do call my own custom function and get that elements inside function for e.g

```
       <input type="text" class="pinBox" placeholder="Enter your pin here.">

        $('.pinBox').initialize();
```

As soon as one execute this there should be a function call which must invokes founction likes below.

```
     function initialize(){
var element = $(this);
$(element).after('<input type="password" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="form-control pincode-input-text first" tabindex="30">'+
'<input type="password" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="form-control pincode-input-text second" tabindex="31">                    '+
'<input type="password" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="form-control pincode-input-text third" tabindex="32">                    '+
'<input type="password" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="form-control pincode-input-text fourth" tabindex="33">);                 '               

}
```

similarly on `$('.pinBox').disableInputBox();` there should be function like . `function disableInputBox(){//whatever i want.}`

Comment: You will have to move the `initialize` function to `jQuery` prototype, if you want to use it in this fashion. As an alternate, you can try `function initialize(el){...}; initialize($('.pinBox'))`

Comment: @Rajesh can u give me a hint with short example.

Comment: @Abhinavmukund, check my answer. This is what you have asked for.

Comment: @Abhinavmukund I have added an answer. Hope it helps. Feel free to comment, if any query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.initialize = function() {
    // below for example I have given a css property to give you idea how you can refer the element by this to play jquery code with.
    this.css( "color", "green" );
    return this;    // By returning `this`, will allow you to attach further jquery functions after calling this `initialize` function to the element
}

$( ".pinBox" ).initialize().addClass( "my-class" );
```

As you can see here, I have applied `initialize` function to `<a>` and then added one more jquery function `addClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom functions to jQuery using `$.fn` or `jQuery.fn`

```js
function initialize(){
  console.log('Element text is :', $(this).text());
}

jQuery.fn.printText = initialize;

$(function(){
  $('span').each(function(index, span){
    $(span).printText();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='temp'>1</span>
<span class='temp'>2</span>
<span class='temp'>3</span>
<span class='temp'>4</span>
<span class='temp'>5</span>
```

You can also pass your element as an argument

```js
function printText(el){
  console.log('Element text is :', $(el).text());
}

$(function(){
  $('span').each(function(index, span){
    printText(span);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='temp'>1</span>
<span class='temp'>2</span>
<span class='temp'>3</span>
<span class='temp'>4</span>
<span class='temp'>5</span>
```

---

Which to use?

- Any function added to `jQuery` will be lost if another jQuery is loaded. Libraries like `jqLite` and few others also use `$` and overrides it. In such case, you will loose your function.
- Any custom function accessing element as argument can be very useful and can be exported to a utility. Such function can be made generic and can be used freely, but you will have to load the file to make them available. You might also have to add handling, if your function has to be specific for certain elements.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on when you want the function to be executed... It could be on page load, or binded on a event, in the next code a few examples:

```
// on page load:
$(function() {
   initialize();
});

// on event binding:
$('.classname').on('click', function() {
  initialize();
});
```

Note, if the function should do something with the object, you need to pass it... for example:

```
$(function() {
   initialize(  $('.pinBox') );
});
function initialize( elem ){
   elem.after( ... );
};
```

Or if the event is always on the same object:

```
$(function() {
   initialize();
});
function initialize(){
     $('.pinBox').after( ... );
};
```

Comment: i am not looking something on click.I am aware about how click events works in jquery.

Comment: Then explain what you are looking for, because the question is not that clear!

Comment: @LinkinTED, he wants to have a kind of own jQuery plugin. Like we do have $('div').datepicker(); Like that way he wants to have own function to call.

Comment: If that is the case, then look at this link: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/